# how to find the max of a field and group by one field in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: I am trying to find the max of a count1 field and group it by sname]

I have the following table with 4 columns and I want max of count1 and group it by sname. Max of count1 is giving me the max but when i am doing group by sname, it is taking wrong cname along with sname.
      What I am expecting is s1  c2   30 and s2  c1  40. can anybody help me out with mysql query

Comment: How can anyone see your screenshot?!

Comment: Don't forget to make `id` auto-increment.

Comment: Yeah I know!!!! I am sorry about the screenshot

Comment: This is just a sample data..... I created this table just for testing purpose. id is autoincremented in main table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT g.sname AS sname, g.cname AS cname, g.count1 AS total 
FROM giriya AS g
   INNER JOIN (SELECT cname, MAX(count1) AS countMax GROUP BY cname) AS ss
   ON g.cname = ss.cname AND g.count1 = ss.countMax
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but there was small change in the query
SELECT g.sname, g.cname, g.count1 AS total 
FROM giriya AS g
   INNER JOIN (SELECT cname, MAX(count1) AS countMax from giriya GROUP BY cname) AS ss
   ON g.cname = ss.cname AND g.count1 = ss.countMax

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake!  I'll fix that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT g.sname, g.cname, g.count1 AS total FROM giriya AS g 
INNER JOIN (SELECT cname, MAX(count1) AS countMax from giriya GROUP BY cname) AS ss
 ON g.cname = ss.cname AND g.count1 = ss.countMax